# A persistent temporary table?

Tags: mysql, sql, innodb, temp-tables

Right now, I'm using temporary tables in my select queries to speed up the execution. They are created every time I execute the query.

In my current situation, the tables are updated with new data only once per day, so I was thinking that instead of using MySQL's `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE` statement, I'll create a persistent table, which in a sense would be *temporary* since it'd be deleted and recreated after a day. And I could fill it up with the *temporary* data just after I've finished updating the main tables.

Or, will `InnoDB's data buffer` will be smart enough to cache the data for temporary tables itself?

Or is there another way for caching the temporary tables?

I'm also sending along appropriate cache headers with the data loaded using AJAX to reduce server load, and AJAX queries make up about 70% of the read requests sent to mysql.

Is what I'm thinking just a plain waste of disk space and tables are never meant to be used in this fashion, or is it a really bright idea for my situation?

Comment: in a multi-user environment, temp tables are not a good idea, because they are only visible to the connection that created them. I would suggest you create "real" tables for the day, and use 'truncate table' at the end of every day, *after* you have saved the data to persistent tables

Comment: yeah, thats what I thought too, since the data for temp tables doesn't change for a day!

Comment: another detail... if the data is so volatile and the main task is to add data, I would sugest you use MyISAM tables, since they are faster for that kind of task (of course, you have to do some extra work to keep referential integrity, but maybe the additional speed is worth the price)

Comment: Let MySQL do the caching. It should be smart enough to cache what is frequently requested.

Answer (score 3):

I came across a similar issue recently where the CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE came at a significant cost due to continual reuse. I also used the solution that Barranka describes (create once and truncate when finished or before reuse).

To increase performance even more I used InnoDB tables that were created on a RAM disk (ramfs). This gives all the benefits of the InnoDB storage engine with very little IO cost. This is a better solution than using the MEMORY storage engine which, according to Oracle support, is only available for legacy applications and has not been improved or extended for some time.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe looking at MEMORY storage engine might help? I use these for some accept data from an intensive query once a day, where the MEMORY table is then used intensively for a short period of time.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/memory-storage-engine.html