# Where is this temporary SQL file located?

Tags: php, sql, joomla

I am working with an a Joomla project I inherited. The original developer customized the code for the J Business directory. (The issue in this question does not relate directly to JBD but is more of a SQL question)

It looks like he is creating a temporary SQL table to store data for displaying results.

```
$sql_temp="CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 
            cache (id int(11) NOT NULL,
            event_link text,
            . . . 
            start_time varchar(255) NOT NULL,
            INDEX (id))";
```

He then appears to pull the records for the display and insert them into a SQL cache table

```
$ins_qu="INSERT INTO cache (id,event_link,event_na . . . 

mysql_query($ins_qu) or mysql_error();
```

I'm not familiar with using a SQL cache table. What I'm trying to find out is

1. Would this approach fail in a multi user situation? I'm thinking that since it's in the server's memory, it would fail. I did read about a #name table which I think is a session based table but I don't think that applies here.
2. I wanted to look at this table the way I can look at the normal tables in phpmyadmin. Is there any way to do that other than writing a sql call to dump the table? Is there a way to use phpMyAdmin to look at it? (I suspect not)

Comment: it may be in memory, or it could be created where your db files reside.  Largely you can ignore the physical storage aspect.

Comment: For phpmyadmin, you can just execute the query, you cant look at it in a traditional way as it has no table definition as such.  But you can see the results of it.  A possible issue with this method is if the source table changes your temp table will become stale, I'm not really sure of the persistence of the temp table, as it may be per DB connection.

Comment: I try to avoid this kind of thing, as you must already have the data, to insert it into the temp table, so it probably is not a performance benefit, more of a ease of use thing.  For example, you already have the data at hand, then on top of that you add the performance hit of creating a table and filling it with data, to access data you already have at hand.  So it may make that data easier to access and sort, but probably doesn't add any performance benefit.  That is assuming its by connection for persistence, if it's not then you have the stale data issue.  Which may or may not be a real

Comment: Ok, it's per connection see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17000934/a-persistent-temporary-table  further `in a multi-user environment, temp tables are not a good idea, because they are only visible to the connection that created them`